# /_layouts/newnav.aspx?ParentId=1002 unexpected error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have non publishing sharepoint site where i want to add some links to Top Link Bar.
I followed bellow steps.
1)Under look and feel clicked on Top link bar it navigated to /_layouts/topnav.aspx
2)I clicked on New Navigation Link  it navigated to /_layouts/newnav.aspx?ParentId=1002
But with unexpected error.

Please tell let me know the sollution

Comment: Is it SharePoint 2010/2013 on premises or Office 365?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I have the same issue. SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise.